# Is it possible that define an zero or one to zero or one association in EF Code first?

Tags: entity-framework, associations, code-first

I have a *Zero or one to zero or one* association in my domain problem that each [Order] can made from zero or one  [Quotation] and a [Quotation] may not be change to a [Order] how can i model this problem by Entity Framework Code First method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it is possible, assume that we have two class, I explain it's method in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701378/implementing-zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one-relationship-in-ef-code-first-by-fluent/14819265#14819265)