# Implementing Zero Or One to Zero Or One relationship in EF Code first by Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship, fluent

I have two POCO classes:

**Order Class:**

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? QuotationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Quotation Quotation { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

**Quotation Class:**

```
public class Quotation
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    ....   
}
```

- Each `Order` **may** be made from  one or zero quotation, and
- each quotation **may** cause an order.

So I have an "one or zero" to "one or zero" relation, how can I implement this, in `EF` Code first by `Fluent` API?

Comment: `public virtual Quotation Quotation { get; set; }`, no? Why aren't you using properties? Why are all your fields private?

Comment: sorry, i edit my code for properties. my classes are not virtual.

Comment: it's not a virtual class, it's a virutal Navigation Property, in Order class.

Comment: For clarity, you may use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45182785/1941942

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By changing pocos to:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Quotation Quotation { get; set; }
}
public class Quotation
{
    public int QuotationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

and using these mapping files:

```
public class OrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        this.HasOptional(x => x.Quotation)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("OrderId"));
    }
}
 
public class QuotationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Quotation>
{
    public QuotationMap()
    {
        this.HasOptional(x => x.Order)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("QuotationId"));
    }
}
```

we will have this DB(that means 0..1-0..1):

[image]

with special thanks to ([Vahid Nasiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298573/vahidn))

Comment: Both configurations has `WithOptionalPrincipal`?

Comment: Caveat: you have to set both foreign keys. If you only set `Order.Quotation`, only `Qotations.OrderId` is set in the database, not `Order.QuotationId`.

Comment: I tried this and got error: 'The navigation property 'ObjectA' declared on type 'SQLiteTest.Entities.ObjectB' has been configured with conflicting foreign keys.'!?

Comment: What is the replacement for this relationship in EF Core

Comment: This is not really a 0..1 to 0..1 association, it is two separate such associations. This is because there is nothing to ensure that if A -> B that B also -> A. The model could say that a Quotation has an Order, and that that Order has a different Quotation. (eg: Quotation 1 points at Order 1, but Order 1 points at Quotation 2.)

Answer (score 30):

@Masoud's procedure was:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasOptional(o => o.Quotation)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .Map(o => o.MapKey("OrderId"));

modelBuilder.Entity<Quotation>()
            .HasOptional(o => o.Order)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .Map(o => o.MapKey("QuotationId"));
```

It gives:

[image]

By changing the code to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasOptional(o => o.Quotation)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(o=> o.Order);
```

It gives:

[image]

Comment: Masoud's solution did not work properly for me - this solution seems to be the correct one.

Comment: How to do that with DataAnnotations?

Comment: How does it know how to relate them without defining any keys?

Answer (score 8):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620 EF Relationships

An excellent Book
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449317867

Here is a post from developer from Dec 2010.  But still relevant
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/adonetefx/thread/aed3b3f5-c150-4131-a686-1bf547a68804
The above article is a nice summary or the possible combinations here.

A solution where dependant Table has key from Primary table is possible.

If you Want Independent Keys where both are Principals in a PK/FK scenario, i dont think you can do it in Code first with Fluent API. If they share a Key, You are OK.
1:1 optional assumes the dependent uses the key from Primary.

But since you need to save one of the tables before the other. You can check one of the Foreign Keys with code. OR add teh second Foreign to Database after Code first has created it.

You will get close. But EF will complain about conflicting Foreign keys if you want both to be Foreign keys.  Essentially the A depends on B depends A EF doesnt like, even if the columns are nullable and technically possible on the DB.

Here use this test program to try it. Just comment in an out the Fluent API stuff to try some options. 
    **I could NOT get EF5.0 to work with INDEPENDENT PK/FK  0:1  to 0:1**
    But of course there are reasonable compromises as discussed.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
namespace EF_DEMO
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var ctx = new DemoContext();
        var ord =  ctx.Orders.FirstOrDefault();
        //. DB should be there now...
    }
}
public class Order
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Code {get;set;}
public int? QuotationId { get; set; }   //optional  since it is nullable
public virtual Quotation Quotation { get; set; }
  //....
}
public class Quotation
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Code{get;set;}
// public int? OrderId { get; set; }   //optional  since it is nullable
 public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
 //...
}
public class DemoContext : DbContext
{
    static DemoContext()
    {
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DemoContext>());
    }
    public DemoContext()
        : base("Name=Demo") { }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Quotation> Quotations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasKey(t => t.Id)
                    .HasOptional(t => t.Quotation)
                    .WithOptionalPrincipal(d => d.Order)
                    .Map(t => t.MapKey("OrderId"));  // declaring here  via MAP means NOT declared in POCO
        modelBuilder.Entity<Quotation>().HasKey(t => t.Id)
                    .HasOptional(q => q.Order)
            // .WithOptionalPrincipal(p => p.Quotation)  //as both Principals
            //        .WithOptionalDependent(p => p.Quotation) // as the dependent
            //         .Map(t => t.MapKey("QuotationId"));    done in POCO.
            ;
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: thanks, your answer helped me, i found the correct answer and post it.

Answer (score 5):

Adapted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108160/entity-framework-code-first-setting-up-one-to-one-foreign-key-association-usin), try this.

First, fix your classes:

```
public class Order
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public virtual Quotation Quotation { get; set; }
  // other properties
}

public class Quotation
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
  // other properties
}
```

Then use the fluent API like that:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Quotation>()
.HasOptional(quote => quote.Order)
.WithRequired(order=> order.Quotation);
```

Basically, for 1:1 or [0/1]:[0/1] relationships, EF needs the primary keys to be shared.

Comment: thanks, but by this mapping we will have a zero-or-one to one relation. i found the correct answer and post it.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public class OfficeAssignment
> {
>     [Key]
>     [ForeignKey("Instructor")]
>     public int InstructorID { get; set; }
>     [StringLength(50)]
>     [Display(Name = "Office Location")]
>     public string Location { get; set; }
>
>     public virtual Instructor Instructor { get; set; }
> }
> ```
>
> The Key Attribute
>
> There's a one-to-zero-or-one relationship  between the Instructor and the OfficeAssignment entities. An office assignment only exists in relation to the instructor it's assigned to, and therefore its primary key is also its foreign key to the Instructor entity. But the Entity Framework can't automatically recognize InstructorID as the primary key of this entity because its name doesn't follow the ID or classnameID naming convention. Therefore, the Key attribute is used to identify it as the key:

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

using DataAnnotations:

```
public class Order
{
       [Key]
       public int Id {get; set;}

       public virtual Quotation Quotation { get; set; }
}

public class Quotation
{
     [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(Order))]
     public int Id {get; set;}

     public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Note that this is using EF 6.4.4.)

It's fairly straightforward to specify, as long as you don't want foreign key properties:

```
modelBuilder
.Entity<Order>()
.HasOptional(o => o.Quotation)
.WithOptionalPrincipal(q => q.Order);

modelBuilder
.Entity<Quotation>()
.HasOptional(q => q.Order)
.WithOptionalDependent(o => o.Quotation);
```

Notice here the usage of both `WithOptionalPrincipal` and `WithOptionalDependent`. This should give you a single foreign key column on the dependent side (Quotation in the example), but with no foreign key properties. If you want the foreign key on the other side, switch "Dependent" and "Principal" around.

(Note that it is not necessary to have both definitions above; `WithOptionalDependent` will imply the other side is the principal and vice-versa, so you can use only one of them if you wanted, but I find specifying the relationships from both sides helps prevent errors by double declaring things; any conflict will result in a model error to let you know you missed something.)

While there is an index on the foreign key column, the index does not have a unique constraint. While it is possible to add your own unique constraint (which would require a `Key IS NOT NULL` filter), it doesn't seem to work and you will get exceptions when updating relationships in some cases. I think this is related to the "swapping problem" where EF will perform its updates in separate queries, so enforcing uniqueness would prevent EF from "moving" a key in two steps.

EF seems to handle the association itself internally, without a unique DB constraint:

- On either side, assigning an already used reference results in the other usage of the reference being removed automatically. (So if it is already the case that A1 <=> B1 when you opened the context, and then you write A1 => B2, then A1 <=> B1 is removed and A1 <=> B2 is added, regardless of which side you're on.)
- If you try to create a duplicate key by assigning the same reference more than once, EF will throw an exception saying "multiplicity constraint violation". (So in the same context, you wrote both A1 => B1 and A2 => B1, or some similar conflicting mapping.)
- If you update the DB manually to create a duplicate key situation, when EF encounters this it will throw an exception saying "A relationship multiplicity constraint violation occurred...this is a non-recoverable error."

It does not seem possible in EF6 to map a property to the foreign key column (at least with Fluent API). Attempting to do so results in a non-unique column name exception since it tries to use the same name for both the property and the association separately.

Note also that it is technically incorrect to have two foreign keys (ie: one on both sides). Such an arrangement would actually be *two* 0..1 to 0..1 associations since there would be nothing to say that keys on both ends should match. This could maybe work if you enforce the relationship some other way, through the UI and/or possibly a database constraint of some kind.

I also notice that there may be a misunderstanding/miscommunication of exactly what a 0..1 to 0..1 association is. What this means, from my understanding and the way EF seems to consider it as well, is that it is a 1 to 1 association that is optional on both sides. So, you can have objects on either side with no relationship. (Whereas a 1 to 0..1 assocation, objects on one side could exist without a relationship, but objects on the other side would always need an object to relate to.)

But 0..1 to 0..1 does not mean that you can have the association travel in one direction and not the other. If A1 => B1, then B1 => A1 (A1 <=> B1). You cannot assign B1 to A1 without also making A1 relate to B1. This is why it is possible for this association to use only a single foreign key. I think some people may be trying to have an association in which this is not true (A1 relates to B1 but B1 does not relate to A1). But that is really not one association but two 0..1 to 0..1 associations.

Comment: That's exactly the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26795517/861716) and two other answers. What's the reason for telling it yet another time?

Comment: @GertArnold It's not exactly the same, it's very specifically different. That answer is incorrectly creating *two* associations. This is the only answer that correctly shows how to create a single 0..1 to 0..1 association (with fluent API) and explains the details of these kinds of associations.

Comment: @GertArnold actually I see you linked Kenneth's answer not Masoud's. his code is similar but has no explanation and no one has indicated that one side of an association should be dependent and the other principal, and what that means. this is the only answer to not only outline the full specification of the association (with fluent API) but also explain the details of it, such as that this will not work if you want foreign key properties. (I wouldn't answer except that I am documenting the results of my own trial and error despite the incorrect or incomplete answers on this question.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237301/discussion-between-dave-cousineau-and-gert-arnold).

Comment: I was a bit lost in retrying all variations found in several answers (and I'll remove my comments), but the fact remains that EF6 doesn't create the correct model. At the database level it's 1:n. It was all collateral to my main point: it repeats an existing answer.

Comment: @GertArnold I see now why there is no unique constraint: EF will "move" a key in two steps; if a unique constraint exists, then "moving" (swapping) a key could only be done in one step. (I don't know how you could claim this answer is redundant when it is now among the most thorough answers on this topic, anywhere).