# One to one optional relationship using Entity Framework Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-one, ef-fluent-api

We want to use one to one optional relationship using Entity Framework Code First. We have two entities.

```
public class PIIUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? LoyaltyUserDetailId { get; set; }
    public LoyaltyUserDetail LoyaltyUserDetail { get; set; }
}

public class LoyaltyUserDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? AvailablePoints { get; set; }

    public int PIIUserId { get; set; }
    public PIIUser PIIUser { get; set; }
}
```

`PIIUser` may have a `LoyaltyUserDetail` but `LoyaltyUserDetail` must have a `PIIUser`.
We tried these fluent approach techniques.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PIIUser>()
            .HasOptional(t => t.LoyaltyUserDetail)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal(t => t.PIIUser)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

This approach didn't create `LoyaltyUserDetailId` foreign key in `PIIUsers` table.

After that we tried the following code.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LoyaltyUserDetail>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.PIIUser)
            .WithRequiredDependent(t => t.LoyaltyUserDetail);
```

But this time EF didn't create any foreign keys in these 2 tables.

Do you have any ideas for this issue?
How can we create one to one optional relationship using entity framework fluent api?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

EF Code First supports `1:1` and `1:0..1` relationships. The latter is what you are looking for ("one to zero-or-one").

Your attempts at fluent are saying **required on both ends** in one case and **optional on both ends** in the other.

What you need is *optional* on one end and *required* on the other.

Here's an example from the Programming E.F. Code First book

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonPhoto>()
.HasRequired(p => p.PhotoOf)
.WithOptional(p => p.Photo);
```

The `PersonPhoto` entity has a navigation property called `PhotoOf` that points to a `Person` type.  The `Person` type has a navigation property called `Photo` that points to the `PersonPhoto` type.

In the two related classes, you use each type's *primary key*, not *foreign keys*. i.e., you won't use the `LoyaltyUserDetailId` or `PIIUserId` properties. Instead, the relationship depends on the `Id` fields of both types.

If you are using the fluent API as above, you do not need to specify `LoyaltyUser.Id` as a foreign key, EF will figure it out.

So without having your code to test myself (I hate doing this from my head)... I would translate this into your code as

```
public class PIIUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public LoyaltyUserDetail LoyaltyUserDetail { get; set; }
}

public class LoyaltyUserDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? AvailablePoints { get; set; }    
    public PIIUser PIIUser { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<LoyaltyUserDetail>()
  .HasRequired(lu => lu.PIIUser )
  .WithOptional(pi => pi.LoyaltyUserDetail );
}
```

That's saying LoyaltyUserDetails `PIIUser` property is *required* and PIIUser's `LoyaltyUserDetail` property is optional.

You could start from the other end:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PIIUser>()
.HasOptional(pi => pi.LoyaltyUserDetail)
.WithRequired(lu => lu.PIIUser);
```

which now says PIIUser's `LoyaltyUserDetail` property is optional and LoyaltyUser's `PIIUser` property is required.

You always have to use the pattern HAS/WITH.

HTH and FWIW, one to one (or one to zero/one) relationships are one of the most confusing relationships to configure in code first so you are not alone! :)

Comment: Doesn't that limit the user on which FK field to pick? (I think he wants that, but he hasn't reported back so I don't know), as it seems he wants to have an FK field present in the class.

Comment: Agreed. It's a limitation of how EF works. 1:1 and 1:0..1 depend on primary keys. Otherwise I think you are straying into the "unique FK" which is still not supported in EF. :( (You're more of a db expert...is that correct...this is really about a unique FK?)And not going to be in upcoming Ef6 as per: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/299

Comment: Yes @FransBouma, we wanted to use PIIUserId and LoyaltUserId fields as foreign keys. But EF limits us in this situtation as you and Julie mentioned. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @JulieLerman why do you use `WithOptional`? What is the different with `WithRequiredDependent` and `WithRequiredOptional`?

Comment: WithOptional points to a relationship that is optional, e.g. 0..1 (zero or one) because the OP said "PIIUser may have a LoyaltyUserDetail". And your confusion that leads to the 2nd question is beause you've got one of the terms wrong. ;) Those are WithRequiredDependent and WithRequiredPrincipal. Does that make more sense? Pointing to a required end that is either the dependent (aka "child") or principal aka "parent". Even in a one to one relationship where both are equal, EF needs to refer to one as principal & one as dependent. HTH!

Comment: In some situations, particularly when the foreign key is formed by more than one field, you must reference via DataAnnotations which fields are part of the foreign key.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helps me understand the 1 to zero or to 1 mapping.

Comment: This answer is out of date, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394969/ef-core-2-0-0-one-to-one-or-zero-with-fluent-api

Comment: What if you wanted to use data annotations?

Comment: Can you please share what is the equivalent Fluent API in  EF core for this relationship

Answer (score 29):

Just do like if you have one-to-many relationship between `LoyaltyUserDetail` and `PIIUser` so you mapping should be

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LoyaltyUserDetail>()
       .HasRequired(m => m.PIIUser )
       .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(c => c.LoyaltyUserDetailId);
```

EF should create all foreign key you need and just [don't care about WithMany](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations) !

Comment: Julie Lerman's answer was accepted (and should stay accepted, IMHO) because it answers the question and goes into detail about why it's the correct way with backing detail and discussion.  Copy and paste answers are certainly available all over SO and I've used a few myself, but as a professional developers you should be more concerned with becoming a better programmer, not just getting the code to build.  That said, jr got it right, albeit a year later.

Comment: @ClickOk I know this is an old question and comment, but this is not the correct answer because it used one to many as a workaround, this doesn't make a one to one or one to zero relation

Answer (score 3):

There are several things wrong with your code.

A **1:1** relationship is either: **PK<-PK**, where one PK side is also an FK, or **PK<-FK+UC**, where the FK side is a non-PK and has a UC. Your code shows you have **FK<-FK**, as you define both sides to have an FK but that's wrong. I recon `PIIUser` is the PK side and `LoyaltyUserDetail` is the FK side. This means `PIIUser` doesn't have an FK field, but `LoyaltyUserDetail` does.

If the **1:1** relationship is optional, the FK side has to have at least 1 nullable field.

p.s.w.g. above did answer your question but made a mistake that s/he also defined an FK in PIIUser, which is of course wrong as I described above. **So define the nullable FK field in `LoyaltyUserDetail`, define the attribute in `LoyaltyUserDetail` to mark it the FK field, but don't specify an FK field in `PIIUser`.**

You get the exception you describe above below p.s.w.g.'s post, because no side is the PK side (principle end).

*EF isn't very good at 1:1's as it's not able to handle unique constraints.* I'm no expert on Code first, so I don't know whether it is able to create a UC or not.

(edit) btw: A **1:1** B (FK) means there's just 1 FK constraint created, on B's target pointing to A's PK, not 2.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? LoyaltyUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual LoyaltyUser LoyaltyUser { get; set; }
}

public class LoyaltyUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User MainUser { get; set; }
}

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.LoyaltyUser)
            .WithOptionalDependent(c => c.MainUser)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

this will solve the problem on **REFERENCE** and **FOREIGN KEYS**

when **UPDATING** or **DELETING** a record

Comment: This won't work as expected. It results in migrations code that doesn't use LoyaltyUserId as a foreign key, so User.Id and LoyaltyUser.Id will end up with the same value, and LoyaltyUserId will be left empty.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `ForeignKey` attribute to the `LoyaltyUserDetail` property:

```
public class PIIUser
{
    ...
    public int? LoyaltyUserDetailId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LoyaltyUserDetailId")]
    public LoyaltyUserDetail LoyaltyUserDetail { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And the `PIIUser` property:

```
public class LoyaltyUserDetail
{
    ...
    public int PIIUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PIIUserId")]
    public PIIUser PIIUser { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: We tried data annotations before all of the these fluent API approaches. But data annotations didn't work. if you add data annotations you mentioned above, EF throws this exception => Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'LoyaltyUserDetail' and 'PIIUser'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: @İlkayİlknur What happens if you add the `ForeignKey` attribute to only one end of of the relationship? i.e. only on `PIIUser` *or* `LoyaltyUserDetail`.

Comment: Ef throws the same exception.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Why FK at PIIUser? LoyaltyUserDetail has a FK, not PIIUser. So it must be [Key, ForeignKey("PIIUser")] at PIIUserId property of the LoyaltyUserDetail. Try [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: @user808128 You can place the annotation on either the navigation property or the ID, no difference.

Comment: @ThomasBoby Interesting! Do you have a link for the documentation of this?

Comment: @Zero3 F12, it's in the comment. Or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) under "Name"

Answer (score 2):

This is of no use to the original poster, but for anyone still on EF6 who needs the foreign key to be different from the primary key, here's how to do it:

```
public class PIIUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //public int? LoyaltyUserDetailId { get; set; }
    public LoyaltyUserDetail LoyaltyUserDetail { get; set; }
}

public class LoyaltyUserDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? AvailablePoints { get; set; }

    public int PIIUserId { get; set; }
    public PIIUser PIIUser { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<PIIUser>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.LoyaltyUserDetail)
    .WithOptional(t => t.PIIUser)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("LoyaltyUserDetailId"));
```

Note that you can't use the `LoyaltyUserDetailId` field because, as far as I can tell, it can only be specified using the fluent API. (I've tried three ways of doing it using the `ForeignKey` attribute and none of them worked).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that is confusing with above solutions is that the Primary Key is defined as "**Id"** in both tables and if you have primary key based on the table name it wouldn't work, I have modified the classes to illustrate the same, i.e. the optional table shouldn't define it's own primary key instead should use the same key name from main table.

```
public class PIIUser
{
    // For illustration purpose I have named the PK as PIIUserId instead of Id
    // public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PIIUserId { get; set; }

    public int? LoyaltyUserDetailId { get; set; }
    public LoyaltyUserDetail LoyaltyUserDetail { get; set; }
}

public class LoyaltyUserDetail
{
    // Note: You cannot define a new Primary key separately as it would create one to many relationship
    // public int LoyaltyUserDetailId { get; set; }

    // Instead you would reuse the PIIUserId from the primary table, and you can mark this as Primary Key as well as foreign key to PIIUser table
    public int PIIUserId { get; set; } 
    public double? AvailablePoints { get; set; }

    public int PIIUserId { get; set; }
    public PIIUser PIIUser { get; set; }
}
```

And then followed by

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PIIUser>()
.HasOptional(pi => pi.LoyaltyUserDetail)
.WithRequired(lu => lu.PIIUser);
```

Would do the trick, the accepted solution fails to clearly explain this, and it threw me off for few hours to find the cause