# Mapping for one to one with nullable value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-mapping

I have two entity classes, `Contact` and `User`.

The `User` has `ContactID` as foreign key to `Contact`. I can show relation of the `User` to `Contact`.

Now i also need `Contact` to `User` relation with the same foreign key in `User` table (not in `Contact`)

```
public class Contact{
   public int ContactID {get;set;}
   // This relation doesn't work
   // Need to Make this Work
   public User ContactUser {get;set;}
}

public class User {
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public int? ContactID {get;set;}
   // This Relation works
   [ForeignKey("ContactID")]
   public Contact Contact {get;set;}
}
```

So i need to make the `ContactUser` relation work on `Contact`. What kind of mapping should i use?

---

**Edit**

As suggested I used :
`modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasRequired(c => c.ContactUser).WithOptional(pi => pi.Contact);`
I removed `ForeignKey` attribute from `User`, it as causing `Multiplicity...error`

But i get error Like:  `Invalid column name 'User_Id'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a

> One to Zero-or-One Mapping

There is a great anwser here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240362/one-to-one-optional-relationship-using-entity-framework-code-first).

---

In your Case explicit is following required:

- modelBuilder needs the WithOptional-Methode

  `.WithOptional(pi => pi.Contact);`
- no Property for the `ContactID`

### Example for EF 6.0

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public User ContactUser { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

In the DbContext-Class:

```
public class CodeFirstContext : DbContext
{
    public CodeFirstContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CodeFirstContext>());            
    }

    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
          .HasRequired(co => co.Contact)
          .WithOptional(cu => cu.ContactUser);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

In this Case now says User's Contact property is optional and Contact's User property is required.
*I hope this is the right constellation for your project.*

### Console Test

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new CodeFirstContext())
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a name: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            var cont = new Contact { ContactName = name };
            db.Contacts.Add(cont);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var usr = new User { UserName = "MyUsername", Contact = cont };
            db.Users.Add(usr);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var query = from b in db.Contacts
                        orderby b.ContactName
                        select b;

            Console.WriteLine("All contacts in the database:");
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ContactName);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting error: Invalid column name 'User_Id'. Mapping Used :  `modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasRequired(c => c.ContactUser).WithOptional(pi => pi.Contact);`

Comment: Got a working Solution here: http://1drv.ms/1yKLZuR - The Problem roots in the [Key]-Attribute.

Comment: This still didn't work for me, must have got something wrong with my other mappings. I solved it for now with a different method without mapping. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
    public User ContactUser { get; set; }
}
```