# Code First migration when entities have cross references with foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have models that have references to each other:

```
public class Dept
{
    [Key]
    public int DeptId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ManagerId")]
    public Emp Manager { get; set; }

    public int? ManagerId { get; set; }

    public string DeptName { get; set; }
}

public class Emp
{
    [Key]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("DeptId")]
    public Dept Dept { get; set; }

    public int DeptId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I call Add-Migration, I get error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Manager' on type 'App.Dept' is not valid.
>       The foreign key name 'ManagerId' was not found on the dependent type 'App.Emp'.
>       The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

What should I do to create migration with these tables?

**UPD:** Implicit optional Manager does not solve the problem:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Emp>().HasRequired(_ => _.Dept).WithOptional(_ => _.Manager);
```

**UPD2:** Dept:Emp relation is **1:0..1**

**UPD3:** Maybe another relation will be added to Dept model but it will be also 1:0..1:

```
[ForeignKey("ManagerId")]
public Emp CTO { get; set; }
public int? CTOId { get; set; }
```

It is not one to many relation: one department have zero or one manager, and zero or one CTO. At the moment I have only one relation, but I want to name the field ManagerId, not a EmpId.

**UPD4:**
Schema from the beginning of my question with two primary/foreign keys relation (Dept.DeptId/Emp.DeptId, Emp.EmpId/Dept.ManagerId) works in plain SQL. I know workarounds with additional table or without foreign keys, but I need an answer how to make work schema above or why it is not working in EF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One to one optional relationship using Entity Framework Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240362/one-to-one-optional-relationship-using-entity-framework-code-first)

Comment: That is not my case, I have foreign keys in both tables

Comment: is this `1:1` ?

Comment: @Artem you have to get rid of one foreign key. Why do you need both? That might bring inconsistency.

Comment: @raderick Do you know method to define navigation property in EF CodeFirst without foreign key?

Comment: @Artem your `modelBuilder.Entity<Emp>().HasRequired(_ => _.Dept).WithOptional(_ => _.Manager);` code is enough. Please read the question and answers in the question, that is in the first comment.

Comment: I already try it and add first update to question above.

Comment: @Artem so what is exactly your problem? Remove one foreign key, mark both navigational properties with virtual if you need lazy loading, or use .Include() to load them explicitely.

Comment: @raderick If I remove ForeignKey how EF know which field contains identifier?

Comment: @Artem Entity Framework will check your mappings to determine which table of the two has a foreign key and how to build the query. If you remove ManagerId from Dept entity (without touching Manager navigation property) and query Dept including Manager, it will build join using Manager.DeptId column as you marked it in mapping to be connected to your Dept table.

Comment: What is Manager.DeptId? I have no table Manager. I have Depts and Emps tables only.

Comment: @Artem I did a typo, read Manager.DeptId as Emp.DeptId.

Comment: @raderick I think Add-Migration will fail with this option. If you have a working solution please add an answer.

Comment: @Artem can you include desired behavior for your model then? I checked comments for the answer, and now not sure, what kind of relationship you are trying to achieve. From the comment seems that you need some one to many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mainly three way to configure 1-1 relationships (the case of your error is the 3rd explained case).

**Complex types**
The first way is with only one table and using complex types. Choosing this configuration has performance impact (often, overall performances are better than other configurations but it depends on the record size and on how many times you have both records).

In your case you need only to mark one of the entities with `ComplexType` attribute

```
public class Dept
{
    [Key]
    public int DeptId { get; set; }

    public Emp Manager { get; set; }

    public string DeptName { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class Emp
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; } // You can still have this property but it will not be a primary key

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With this model this is the created table

```
CREATE TABLE [Depts] (
 [DeptId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [Manager_EmpId] int not null
, [Manager_Name] text null
, [DeptName] text null
);
```

**Standard foreign key**
The second way is to use a standard foreign key. The model can have navigation properties on both classes, has 2 tables with **independent** primary keys but only 1 table has the foreign key to the other table (you wrote about this configuration on your question). You obtain this configuration overriding `OnModelCreating`.
Using this way there are several configurations you can do using fluent API. The main option is where should EF insert the foreign key.
In every configuration you must have Map method (I explain what happens without the Map method in the third way)

The model is always this

```
public class Dept
{
    [Key]
    public int DeptId { get; set; }

    public Emp Manager { get; set; }

    public string DeptName { get; set; }
}

public class Emp
{
    [Key]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }

    public Dept Department { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

WithRequiredPrincipal (1-1)

> From MSDN:
>   Configures the relationship to be required:required without a navigation property on the other side of the relationship. The entity type being > configured will be the principal in the relationship. The entity type that the relationship targets will be the dependent and contain a foreign > key to the principal.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dept>()
    .HasRequired(_ => _.Manager)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(_ => _.Department)
    .Map(_ => _.MapKey("DepartmentId"));
```

This is the DDL generated

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Depts] (
[DeptId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [DeptName] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [Depts] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Depts_c0491d33] PRIMARY KEY ([DeptId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Emps] (
[EmpId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [Name] text null
, [DepartmentId] int not null
);
ALTER TABLE [Emps] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Emps_c0491d33] PRIMARY KEY ([EmpId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_DepartmentId] ON [Emps] ([DepartmentId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [Emps] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Emps_Depts_DepartmentId] FOREIGN KEY ([DepartmentId]) REFERENCES [Depts] ([DeptId])
```

WithRequiredDependent (1-1)

> From MSDN:
>   Configures the relationship to be required:required without a navigation property on the other side of the relationship.
>   [For me is not clear this explanation, anyway, for the real behaviour see below]

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dept>()
    .HasRequired(_ => _.Manager)
    .WithRequiredDependent(_ => _.Department)
    .Map(_ => _.MapKey("EmpId"));
```

This is the DDL generated

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Depts] (
[DeptId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [DeptName] text null
, [EmpId] int not null
);
ALTER TABLE [Depts] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Depts_bebceea2] PRIMARY KEY ([DeptId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Emps] (
[EmpId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [Name] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [Emps] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Emps_bebceea2] PRIMARY KEY ([EmpId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_EmpId] ON [Depts] ([EmpId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [Depts] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Depts_Emps_EmpId] FOREIGN KEY ([EmpId]) REFERENCES [Emps] ([EmpId])
```

WithOptional (1-0..1)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dept>()
    .HasRequired(_ => _.Manager)
    .WithOptional(_ => _.Department)
    .Map(_ => _.MapKey("ManagerId"));
```

This is the DDL generated

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Depts] (
[DeptId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [DeptName] text null
, [ManagerId] int not null
);
ALTER TABLE [Depts] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Depts_ee5245bb] PRIMARY KEY ([DeptId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Emps] (
[EmpId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [Name] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [Emps] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Emps_ee5245bb] PRIMARY KEY ([EmpId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_ManagerId] ON [Depts] ([ManagerId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [Depts] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Depts_Emps_ManagerId] FOREIGN KEY ([ManagerId]) REFERENCES [Emps] ([EmpId])
```

You can use other methods to obtain similar configurations. I dont show here every example but we can mix these configurations

`HasOptional`/`WithRequired`
`HasOptional`/`WithOptionalDependent`
`HasOptional`/`WithOptionalPrincipal`

**EF Default 0..1-1 1-0..1 1-1 configuration**
This is how EF is interpreting your configuration. In this case EF generates 2 tables with **dependent** primary keys. On one table there is an independent primary key (in your case identity(1,1)) and on the other table you have a primary key that is also the foreign key. This is the default configuration. *This is the only way to have foreign keys on both tables* (not 2 constraints, no way to have 2 circular contraints, see below)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dept>()
    .HasRequired(_ => _.Manager)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(_ => _.Department);
```

This is the DDL generated

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Depts] (
[DeptId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [DeptName] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [Depts] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Depts_b91ed7c4] PRIMARY KEY ([DeptId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Emps] (
[EmpId] int not null
, [Name] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [Emps] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Emps_b91ed7c4] PRIMARY KEY ([EmpId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_EmpId] ON [Emps] ([EmpId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [Emps] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Emps_Depts_EmpId] FOREIGN KEY ([EmpId]) REFERENCES [Depts] ([DeptId])
```

This should be 1-1 relationship but if we look better there is one missing constraint. The primary key of the Dept table should be a foreign key for the second table. Why EF did not insert that constraint? Because we will violate always a constraint so we could not insert records on tables (also inside a transaction a reference key constraint can be violated).

Changing the configuration to `HasRequired`/`WithRequiredDependent` we obtain the table with the independent primary key will be the Emps table

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Dept>()
    .HasRequired(_ => _.Manager)
    .WithRequiredDependent(_ => _.Department);
```

This is the DDL generated

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Depts] (
[DeptId] int not null
, [DeptName] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [Depts] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Depts_58ab8622] PRIMARY KEY ([DeptId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Emps] (
[EmpId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [Name] text null
);
ALTER TABLE [Emps] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Emps_58ab8622] PRIMARY KEY ([EmpId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_DeptId] ON [Depts] ([DeptId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
ALTER TABLE [Depts] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Depts_Emps_DeptId] FOREIGN KEY ([DeptId]) REFERENCES [Emps] ([EmpId])
```

You can use other methods to obtain similar configurations. I dont show here every example but we can mix these configurations

`HasOptional`/`WithRequired`
`HasOptional`/`WithOptionalDependent`
`HasOptional`/`WithOptionalPrincipal`

Answer (score 1):

From your class code you have the following

For 1-1 and 1-0..1, same primary key should appear in both tables and in your design its not the  case since both tables will have their own primary key

Now, based on the code you put, the configuration should be as follows

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Dept>()
             .HasKey(t => t.DeptId)
             .HasOptional(t => t.Manager)
             .WithRequired(t => t.Dept);
```

but this will not mean  a 1-1 or 1-0..1 relation.

if you want to convert your codes to become 1-0..1, then you code should be like this

1. Remove the EmpId from  the class Emp
2. The configuration should look like

   ```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Emp>()
               .HasKey(t => t.DeptId)
               .HasRequired(t => t.Dept);
   modelBuilder.Entity<Dept>()
               .HasKey(t => t.DeptId)
               .HasOptional(t => t.Manager)
               .WithRequired(t => t.Dept);
   modelBuilder.Entity<Dept>()
               .HasOptional(t => t.Manager)
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(t => t.ManagerId)
               .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
   ```

for more information about the relations, you might read this article [Configure One-to-Zero-or-One Relationship:](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Hope this will help you

Comment: What you mean by "same primary key"? I need EmpId in Emp, and DeptId in Dept.

Comment: If each table will have its  own primary key, this is not a 1-1 relation, the 1-1 relation will be translated as same primary key in both  tables and second table has the primary key as foreign key as well

Comment: I am editing my answer to add more information that I hope it will help you to distinguish between  the cases

Comment: @Artem  I can propose a different structure about how to store the information, which will be Emp , Dept, and DeptManager ( a  many to many table between Emp and Dep since the Managers can be promoted to be manager to another department and again another manager will be head of the previous department or the manager resigned, so DeptManager can hold  the history in addition  to the current manager

Comment: Maybe I use wrong terms, but schema from my question (one department have zero or one manager, and zero or one CTO) is working in plain SQL without DeptManager table. I want to know how to make it work in EF or why it is not working with EF.