# one-zero-one relation ef codefrist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, ef-fluent-api

i have 3 class

```
public class StockDef
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StockType { get; set; }
    public virtual OfficeStock SayanStock { get; set; }
    public virtual AgentStock AgentStock { get; set; }
    //....
}

public class OfficeStock
{
    public virtual StockDef StockDef { get; set; }
    //....
}

public class AgentStock
{
    public virtual StockDef StockDef { get; set; }
    //......
}
```

every StockDef object definitely have (one OfficeStock or one AgentStock).
and every OfficeStock definitely have one StockDef.
and every AgentStock definitely have one StockDef.
how can I implement this, in EF Code first by fluent API?
tnx

Comment: You need CHECK Constraint if you want : one `officeStock` or one `AgentStock` for `StockDef` and I think, it's not possible with fluent Api. but you can add it manually. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245449/is-it-possible-to-add-check-constraint-with-fluent-api-in-ef7)

Comment: tnx for response @iamnapo <br> I should be how the final table in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't configure StockDef (the constraint "only one property can be compiled") with fluent api, you have to add a custom validation implementing IValidatableObject interface.

You can also add a constraint (a trigger?) on the database so you can avoid that someone else inserts wrong records.

Also, about 1-1 relationship configuration you can have a look here 
[Code First migration when entities have cross references with foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492757/code-first-migration-when-entities-have-cross-references-with-foreign-keys/39567129#39567129)

Comment: why?? you say it's not possible StockDef can only one OfficeStock or AgentStock?

Comment: Probably I did not understand. StockDef can have one OfficeStock and one AgentStock? I mean, can be `StockDef.OfficeStock` and `StockDef.AgentStock` both compiled?

Comment: StockDef can have one OfficeStock OR one AgentStock

Comment: I don't think that you can configure this constraint with fluent api. I think you have to implement `IValidatableObject ` otherwise you can have one OfficeStock AND one AgentStock.