# EF Core 2.0.0 One to One-or-Zero with Fluent Api

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In Fluent Api at ***EF Core 2.0.0***, there aren't any methods `HasRequired` and `HasOptional`, and i have tow Models, Person and Employee:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; } // Optional
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person {get; set; } // Required
    }
```

> - `Person` May to have Employee: `Optional`
> - `Employee` Should have Person: `Required`

How to apply these convetions in database.

Comment: I strongly recommend reading [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) section of the documentation. In your case, it would be enough to remove the `EmployeeId` from `Person`.

Comment: I have read this section, i want to know about one-to-one relationship, Employee is optional for Person but every Employee should have Person

Comment: How about **Required and Optional Relationships** and **Other Relationship Patterns - One-to-one** parts from the link? And *Blog -> BlogImage* sample - it's exactly like your case.

Comment: @SinaLotfi did you find any answer to solve the question ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just specify int? as EmployeeId property type.

BTW, no need to make navigation properties virtual.