# PredicateBuilder, build predicate over 2 tables using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, predicatebuilder

I've got a complex problem, but the explanation of it is even more complex (I think). But I'll give it a try anyway, if it's not clear, please ask me to elaborate.

I have a table called `UserService`. A service is whatever a user offers, for example a band that plays in a cafe. Another one is DJ and room. Here is what the table looks like:

```
[Table("UserService")]
public class UserService
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Information { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

`Type` is an `enum` for all possible services.

The room is a special case because it requires some additional fields that are not always required/needed, like address and geolocation. For these reasons I created a separate table for it:

```
public class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserServiceId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public DbGeography GeoLocation { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserServiceId")]
    public virtual UserService UserService { get; set; }
}
```

When filtering on a user service (all combo's are possible), which I construct with a [PredicateBuilder](http://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/).

Suppose the user selects Band and Room but when room is selected, the user should also pass a city or zip code (or anything else to get a geolocation from) and a distance in miles to look for a room. How can I build the predicate over 2 tables?

If I do this:

```
var userServices = PredicateBuilder.Create<UserService>(x => lstTypes.Contains(x.Type));
```

Than I can't do anything with the `GeoLocation` field in the Room table, because `UserService` doesn't have it. So this won't work:

```
userServices = userServices.And(x => x.GeoLocation.Distance(geo) < distance);
```

Also, I need these userservices combined because of the `Orderby().Skip().Take()` I use. So this will get messed up if I separate them and going twice to the database because of this.

I was thinking about adding a navigation property `Room` to `UserService` but I'm not sure what this might do in the short and long term. Since it's not always required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have things now, `Room`s effectively have a many-to-one relationship with `UserService` because they have a foreign key to that table.

You could leave this as-is, and add a `Rooms` property to `UserService`, in which case you'd have to see whether `x => x.Rooms.Any(r => r.GeoLocation.Distance(geo) < distance)`. If there is no room associated with the service, then the `.Any()` would obviously return false.

However, you're making it sound like a Room is simply an optional property off of `UserService`, in which case you may want to make `UserServiceId` *its primary key as well as its foreign key*. Then your predicate would be `x => x.Room.GeoLocation.Distance(geo) < distance`. The weird thing is that while C# would throw an exception from this code, the generated SQL ends up propagating null values so it should come out effectively `false` if `x.Room` turns out to be null.

Comment: It's a one-to-one relationship, what makes you think many-to-one? Do you mean `public Room Room {get; set;}`? Or with the `virtual` key word? And yes, the room is 'optional' because the user decides what kind of service he/she offers. If its 'dj' than no point of giving a room up since you're invited to a location in stead of having it at the house of the user.

Comment: @Quoter: What happens if you go to your database and insert two Rooms with the same `UserServiceId`?

Comment: Nothing, it will just get committed. Why? It's 1 pm here, I can't think straight anymore, my bad.

Comment: @Quoter: The answer *should be* "The database won't let me because the constraints won't allow it," but I'm guessing that is not the case here, because the standard way to set up a one-to-one relationship is how I described it--a primary key that is also the foreign key. Other developers, looking at your database tables, would say that you have a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: But yes, you've got the general idea: once you've got your schema set up to prevent adding more than one room per UserService, you add a `Room` navigation property in the usual way. But you recognize that the Room property may be null for some UserService objects.

Comment: Could you show me how the models would look like exactly and maybe if something needs to be done with `FluentApi`? I keep getting an error when Update-Database command is executed that starts with `An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships...`

Comment: @Quoter: I'm afraid I'm not experienced with code-first, but I imagine [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701378/implementing-zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one-relationship-in-ef-code-first-by-fluent) will give you what you need.

Comment: I implemented that like a half a day ago and it seems to work after extensively testing. Thanks.