# Optional One-to-One Relationship - Code First C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship

I'm trying to do a two way optional relationship between two entities:

- Series
- Fixture

A Series has an optional Fixture and a Fixture has an optional Series. Here are the two Entity classes I have so far.

```
public class Fixture : IEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int? SeriesId { get; set; }

    public virtual Series Series { get; set; }
}

public class Series : IEntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? FixtureId { get; set; }

    public virtual Fixture Fixture { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to update the database with this I get the following error:

> "Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'Fixture' and 'Series'. The principal end of this association
>   must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API
>   or data annotations."

So I added this line to my `ModelBuilder` and the update database runs fine and the tables are created.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Fixture>().HasOptional(f => f.Series).WithOptionalPrincipal(f => f.Fixture);
```

But when I view my database in SQL there is an unnecessary column named `Fixture_Id` which makes me assume my entities setup is incorrect.

### [image: Series table example]

Also when I return a list of Series in debug mode I can see that one of the Series has a FixtureId as shown in the image above, but the relationship to the Fixture is null.

Hope I provided enough information.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Zero Or One to Zero Or One relationship in EF Code first by Fluent API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701378/implementing-zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one-relationship-in-ef-code-first-by-fluent)