# one to zero relation with hasforeignkey

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have the following classes.

```
class Zero
{
    One One { get; set; }
    int OneId { get; set; }
}

class One
{
    Zero Zero { get; set}
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Zero>()
        .HasRequired(e => e.One)
        .WithOptional(a=>a.Zero)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.OneId);//<--error
```

there is no `HasForeignKey` after `WithOptional`, only after `WithMany`

What can I do to get the same results ?

Comment: `HasForeignKey` is missing for a purpose (not supported for `one-to-one` relationships). Do you really need separate FK in `Zero`? EF by default uses shared primary key association for this type of relationship, i.t. the `Zero` PK will also be FK. If you are not constrained to existing database, I would recommend using that strategy.

Comment: I need the FK in my class Zero

Comment: Ok, then the only option you have is to create independent association, i.e. without explicit FK property. Remove the `int OneId { get; set; }` and use `.Map(m => m.MapKey("OneId"))` fluent API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF 6.X you can take a lok to this stackoverflow post 
[Implementing Zero Or One to Zero Or One relationship in EF Code first by Fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14701378/implementing-zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one-relationship-in-ef-code-first-by-fluent)

In EF Core you can try this

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity()
                .HasOne(p => p.Link)
                .WithOne(i => i.UrlProvider)
                .HasForeignKey(b => b.UrlProviderId);
        }
```